# Can the Porter Stemmer return the affix rather than the stem?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, porter-stemmer

I am working on a project in which I am trying to calculate the percentage of inflectional morphology of multiple corpora in order to compare them.

I know how to use the nltk Porter Stemmer in order to get the root of the word, but it would be much more helpful for me if I could return the affix rather than the root. If I could do that, I could just count the number of affixes the stemmer cut off ("ly" "ed" etc) and compare it to the total number of words. It might be a simple flip, but I can't figure out how to do this with the roots.

Comment: In general, what you want is not possible. For example, the stem of "shy", as reported by Porter, is "shi", which is not a proper subset of the original word.

Comment: @DYZ you're right. Maybe a more general automatic solution is look for the difference between input and output words. Something like "extract the maximum substring", then use the difference according to the specific needs. For example: porter("shy") = "shi", then, "y"-->"i", so it marks the affix or set of them.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are talking about inflectional morphology? Inflection means that the part of speech remains unchanged and the word is changed only to express some grammatical features (like past). Inflectional affixes are always suffixes and, if we don't take irregular words into account, there's a limited number of them (`-ed`, `-ing`, `-er`, `-est`, `-s`, `-es`).

However, it seems like you're talking about derivational morphology because there might be only one inflectional suffix so it doesn't make sense for me to count them (it's `0` if it's lemma and `1` if it's inflected form).

If you're talking about derivational affixes, then what you're looking for is called morpheme segmentation/tokenization and it's not an easy thing to do because word derivation processes are influenced by many factors and aren't well defined. In easy cases, we just append a suffix (or prepend prefix) to the root, however there're cases when some letters in the root are dropped (`arrive` -> `arrival`), changed (`try` -> `tried` or more unusual, like `assume` -> `assumption`) or even appended (`drama` -> `dramatist`). Moreover, you need to have some semantic knowledge database because without it it's not possible to determine the morphemes correctly in all the cases. For example, the word `remember` can be tokenized into `re-` + `member`. Without semantics, such morphological analysis looks quite reasonable as `re-` is a quite popular prefix meaning repetition and `member` is an existing word. Knowing semantic relationship would tell us that `member` and `remember` are not related (I believe they might be related etymologically, but in the modern language the relationship is not that obvious).

Checkout [Lingua Robot](https://www.linguarobot.io/) and [Morfessor](http://morpho.aalto.fi/projects/morpho/). The first one is an API that parses English [Wiktionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiktionary) and provides the data in a JSON. Affixes are available as part of this JSON. Morfessor is a tool for morphological segmentation, so it does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to get the affix, just removing the root (porter result) from the original word form should work.

Consider this pseudo-code:

```
word = "hopeful"
stem_word = porter(word)           #  stem_word should be "hope"
affix = word.remove(stem_word)     # affix should be "ful"
```

Other possible alternative which maybe can help you is to use a "hyphenator", since it can potentially divide words into morphemes, not just split the word by the root. Therefore, it could give you more affix information.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. However, I get the attribute error: str has no attribute remove. Is there another way to delete a portion of a string

Comment: Replace the last line with `affix=word.split(stem_word)[-1]`. This works only if the affix is not-null.

Comment: Hi Will, yes, that error is because ".remove" is pseudo-code (it does not belong to any programming language), it's just to show you the idea. If you are working with python try @DYZ's suggestion, it should work. Then, if this works for you, please dont forget to accept my answer :)